# Приложение EXPO закрывается сразу после запуска

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, styled-components

Приложение EXPO закрывается сразу после запуска. При запуске через Expo Go такой проблемы нет, всё работает. Как такое можно решить?

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start --dev-client",
        "android": "expo run:android",
        "ios": "expo run:ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.3",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
        "expo": "~48.0.15",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.7",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
        "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

```
{
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 3.12.0"
    },
    "build": {
        "development": {
            "distribution": "internal",
            "android": {
                "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug",
                "buildType": "apk"
            },
            "ios": {
                "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
            }
        },
        "preview": {
            "distribution": "internal",
            "android": {
                "buildType": "apk"
            }
        },
        "production": {}
    },
    "submit": {
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой.Как решили?